# quick way to put quotes around each service's code

Tags: r, double-quotes

I've got a little problem. 
When I try to create a variable

```
my_var <- c(17.1, 17.10.1, 17.11, 17.12, 17.13)
```

it returns an error

> 'Error: unexpected numeric constant'

I know that I need to put it in quotes, but there is a lot of code.
Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider how you are getting the text *into* R to begin with instead of working it in this format; I'm guessing you are pasting it from something else, suggesting at a minimum that when you copy it (before pasting), you can replace @RonahShah's answer's `"17...13"` with `strsplit(readLines("clipboard"), ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the numbers and add quotes in start and end

```
"17.1, 17.10.1, 17.11, 17.12, 17.13"
```

then split on comma and remove whitespace

```
my_var1 <- trimws(strsplit("17.1, 17.10.1, 17.11, 17.12, 17.13", ",")[[1]])
my_var1
#[1] "17.1"    "17.10.1" "17.11"   "17.12"   "17.13"
```

This would give same output if you had applied quotes manually

```
my_var <- c("17.1", "17.10.1", "17.11", "17.12", "17.13")
identical(my_var, my_var1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Code golf: `strsplit("17.1, 17.10.1, 17.11, 17.12, 17.13", "[, ]+")`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `scan` to do this

```
scan(text = str1, what ="", sep = ",", quiet = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
#[1] "17.1"    "17.10.1" "17.11"   "17.12"   "17.13"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "17.1, 17.10.1, 17.11, 17.12, 17.13"
```